# How to find count of last records from a special record

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find count of last records from special record to last record. 
Exp :

```
id   name
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d
```

Count of last records from where name is b is 2

Count of last records from where name is a is 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is sorted by name :

```
select count(*) from table where name > ?
```

else if its sorted by another field like Id :

```
select count(*) from table where Id > ?
select count(*) from table where Id > (select Id from table where name = ?)
```